# Error Loading Operating System

Tags: windows

I have a hard drive that says Error Loading Operating System.  Previously it said, "Can Not find Windows/System32/Config" and I ran the copy over from the repair directory and that fix that, but now I get the previously mentioned error.  The hard drive is seen by the BIOS, but that's about all I know.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See this article : [How to Deal With "Error Loading Operating System"](http://www.iqio.org/how-to-deal-with-error-loading-operating-system).

It contains several suggestions on how to deal with this problem, among then is doing a repair installation of XP. Do this only as the last step, although I believe that this is probably the only solution that will work.

If you have important unsaved data on the disk, try to salvage it first using a rescue CD or a Linux live CD.